# allow backslah url symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, url, twig, backslash

i'm doing a file explorer application with symfony 2.5 and Php 5.3.13.

Here my scanAction who lists files of the directory :

```
public function listAction($client)
{
    $dir_clients = $this->container->getParameter('dir_clients');
    $dir_inter = ''.$dir_clients.'\\'.$client.'\\Interventions';

    $interv = scandir($dir_inter);
    $interv = array_slice($interv, 2);
    $to_remove = array('Thumbs.db');
    $interv_list = array_diff($interv, $to_remove);

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:pilotage.html.twig', array(

   // Here 'liste' = array of files in 'dir_interventions'
  // 'dir_interventions' is a string of the directory

        'liste' => $interv_list,
        'dir_interventions' => $dir_inter,
    ));
}
```

Here my pilotage.html.twig :

```
{% for files in liste %}
     <div style="text-align:left";>
        <a target="" href="{{ path('affiche_pilotage', { 'repertoire':dir_interventions, 'file':files  }) }}">{{ files }}&nbsp;</a>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My affiche_pilotage path :

```
affiche_pilotage:
    pattern:  /pilotage/{repertoire}/file}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:affichePilotage}
    requirements:
        repertoire: .+
        file: .+
```

Finally my affichePilotageAction();

```
public function affichePilotageAction( $repertoire , $file )
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents(''.$repertoire.'/'.$file.''));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    $response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename='. $file);

    return $response;
}
```

My problem is that the generated `<a href=':D/svn/blabla/blabla/web\client\Interventions/filename'</a>`

because of the backslashes .\.

How can i resolve this issue ?
Thanks all !

Comment: can you try $dir_inter = rawurlencode( $dir_clients . '\\' . $client . '\\Interventions');

Comment: $dir_inter = rawurlencode('' . $dir_clients . '\\' . $client . '\\Interventions');

        var_dump($dir_inter); => string 'D%3A%2Fbla%2Fsvn-mtt-ppc%2Fbla%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscripts%2Fapp%2F..%2Fweb%2Fperformance-client%2F1.DonneesClients%5CAXA%5CInterventions' (length=166)

        $interv = scandir($dir_inter);
        var_dump($interv); => boolean FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did like that : 'interventions_param' is set as 'Interventions' in config.yml as a parameter

```
  {% for files in liste %}
  {% set repertoire = dir_client ~ '/' ~ client ~ '/' ~ interventions_param %}
        <div style="text-align:left";>
            <li><a target="" href="{{ path('affiche_excel', { 'repertoire':repertoire, 'file':files  }) }}">{{ files }}</a></li>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it unsecure ?